# Is there any specific library to fetch port API?

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

I am writing a web application at work that uses database resources that we have in Azure SQL on an external server and for this purpose I downloaded the drivers, uploaded the appropriate code to pom.xml and everything works, but I still need to connect to our "IDOSELL" application it has tab for developers. I was looking for information there, everything seemed fine for communication I used wsdl (which contains soap) and something is going on here, from what the compiler spit out everything indicates that some class is missing, which is why specific object / method definitions are underlined with the information "cannot be resolved to a type". The question is do you have any ideas what I could have done wrong?

(Below I attach the necessary code and a fragment of the pom.xml file)

```
package app_008;
   
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;    
import java.security.MessageDigest;            
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;             
import java.util.Date;                         
import java.net.MalformedURLException;        
import java.net.URL;                          
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;              
import javax.xml.ws.Service;    

public class App 
{
    public static String generateKey(String hashedPassword) 
    {
       ........
    }

    public static String hashPassword(String password) 
    {
       ........
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Creating a web service client for an API service
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://instalator/api/?wsdl");
            QName serviceName = new QName("http://instalator/api/",                                                  "ApiOrdersService");
            Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);
    
            //Get Port API
            ApiOrdersPortType apiPort = service.getPort(ApiOrdersPortType.class);
    
            // Credential setting
            String userLogin = "userLogin";
            String authenticateKey = "authenticateKey";
    
            // Session key generation based on password hash and date
            String hashedPassword = hashPassword("yourPassword");
            String sessionKey = generateKey(hashedPassword);
    
            // Sending an API request
            GetPackagesRequestType request = new GetPackagesRequestType();
            request.setAuthenticate(new AuthenticateType());
            request.getAuthenticate().setUserLogin(userLogin);
            request.getAuthenticate().setAuthenticateKey(authenticateKey);
    
            //Adding other request parameters
            ParamsType params = new ParamsType();
            params.setDeliveryPackageNumbers(new String[] { "deliveryPackageNumbers" });
            params.setEvents(new GetPackagesSystemItemRequestTypes[] { new  GetPackagesSystemItemRequestTypes() });
            params.getEvents()[0].setEventType(EventType.ORDER);
            params.getEvents()[0].setEventsIds(new int[] { 1 });
            params.setReturnLabels(true);
            request.setParams(params);
    
            // API method call
            GetPackagesResponseType response = apiPort.getPackages(request);
    
            // Response processing
            // ...
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is a list of errors from the compiler:

[image]

P.S

Password encryption methods and login details have been changed for the needs of the question :)